# Difference Between Visual Studio Express 2013 and Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-express

Please i'm confused, I need to buy Visual Studio Express 2013 for my software development need. I couldn't find visual studio express 2013 in the market. I was told that visual studio express 2013 and visual studio 2013 are same product. Is this right?

Comment: Before you post, summarize the problem and provide details and example for that to describe what you’ve tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio Express (whatever year/version it has) was the free 'light' version of the Visual Studio product, with some of the more powerful features missing.

However, for VS-2013 (and later versions), you can download the "Community" version of the full product **for free**. The Community versions have most (all?) of the main features included but cannot be used for commercial software development. Also, you don't get the full on-line technical support that the "Professional" and "Enterprise" versions include in the purchase price.

Comment: Can Visual studio 2013 be used as a complete replacement for Visual studio express 2013?

Comment: @user3867365 - Yes. But so can any later release of Visual Studio. Any reason why you specifically need the 2013 version?

Comment: PS: You can get what you need (if you really need Express 2013) here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/

Comment: I'm building a windows desktop application using Electron JS and needed to communicate with a COM port using serialport nodejs module. In order to get the serialport module working, I have to compile it using electron-rebuild npm package. So installing Visual Studio Express 2013 is one of the requirements to rebuild the serialport module. Here is a link to the serialport module and installation guide: https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport-builds-electron

Comment: @user3867365 - Then the download link should answer your problem!